# How to detect what is causing a php script to load slow

Tags: php

I am having a bit of an issue with a php scropt. When I open my site (hosted locally) it pauses for 1-2 seconds then it loads the page.

the database where I am readying data from is very small and has indexes. The queries are quick.

My PHP code is somewhat optimized, and my databases are indexed.
PHP5.3.19 is installed on Windows 2008 R2 Server (Intel Xeon(R) CPU E5-2400 0 @2.20 GHz (2 processors) 16GB of RAM and MySQL Server in installed on a **different** server. Both servers are on the same network so all connection should be internal.

I also use PDO to connect to my databases.

How can I determine what is causing the extra delay?
What things can I check for to expedite the page load?

Thanks

Comment: You should show some code, will be easier to help.

Comment: First, determine whether it's in PHP, or in the webserver (or further on): time it from the beginning of the request in PHP to the end: is this as slow as you experience, or quick and is the problem elsewhere? If it's quick, possible causes I can think OTOH are DNS (don't let your webservers log do DNS lookups!) or network issues. If it's the PHP itself, run it with xdebug, profile it, and it will tell you how long everything takes & make it easy to pin down.

Comment: xdebug is great for this. On my Windows Machine Wamp does that short pause too.

Comment: @Wrikken I am not sure how to time it but I followed the example in the link http://www.phpjabbers.com/measuring-php-page-load-time-php17.html and I am seeing 2.7345 seconds. DNS, it could be as when we access the site we use the server name as a domain http://servername/application/index.php. How do I run php with xdebung mode without effective my users? this is a production server.  thanks

Comment: @Mike: indeed, then it's in the PHP code. It is indeed a bad idea to run `xdebug` on a production server. Fire up your test-server, which should be as much like your production server as possible, and run an `xdebug` profile there.

Comment: Also, look in your databases slow query log. If it's just 1 or 2 offending queries they can most likely be found there (keep in mind that mysql can nowadays be configured to use microseconds rather then the old seconds).

Comment: @Wrikken Unfortunately I don't has a test environment. I am not sure if there is a way to turn on xdebug at run time? I have 2 identical scripts running on the same server one for testing and one for production, if i can turn xdebun at run time them I should be able to turn it only for the testing script. Please Advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to my Experience I can say, there might JavaScript or any script files which you might have called in your code. 
if browser find any missing script(due to wrong path or what so ever reason it may be) file then it search for it again and again until the searching time is out, which is around 2 to 5 sec, depending on the setting of the browser.

Comment: If it was JS Mike should not be experiencing a delay before the page loads.

Comment: I made an extra check now, all files do exists and I don't see any issue in the javascript console.

Comment: @Popnoodles is right, I want to know the delay is the after the load of the HTML/CSS(Text of the Page) or the delay before showing nothing on page?